# wordpress jQuery causing failed chrome audit tool - render blocking

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on my theme, and test in here and there in chrome audits to see how it's looking as I'm working on the site.

I noticed that when using jQuery as a dependent of a script, it fails chrome audit and says that the script is render blocking. Is there another way or another option i should put in my enqueue script to stop this from happening.

My code. (Shortened for easier reading)

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
function site_assets() {    
  wp_enqueue_script('force-easy-scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/force.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);   
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'site_assets');
```

**RENDERED HTML**

```
    <!-- END MAIN SITE CONTENT -->
    <footer>

    </footer>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://smtg-new/wp-content/themes/SMTG_THEME/js/force.min.js'></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**CHROMES AUDIT**
[image: jquery fails chrome audit in wordpress]

Now for testing purposes, I have 4 scripts that I'm enqueuing now that all reside right before the closing body tag. All depending on jQuery. I'll combine them later on. But none of those are showing as render blocking, considering there at the bottom of the page.

How can I get wordpress's built in jQuery to not be render blocking? It's putting a pretty big hit in time and it's frustrating. I rather not dequeue it's own version of jQuery and use mine. I don't do any fancy stuff with it so I don't need the latest version. There version is totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Autoptimize plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/ . The plugin provides an option ( under advanced settings ) to disable jquery from loading in the head part. Please note that can trigger some issues ( most likely with plugins that are jquery dependant - such as Gravity Forms. ). Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I saw that plugin somewhere in my research. Is there a "non plugin" way to do it? I can handle minimizing my js and css on my own. I don't really want to install a plugin for that functionality just to use one thing in it. Seems like a waste of valuable space and load time to me.

Comment: The purpose of Autoptimze specifically is to make your website faster for google page speed. But you can handle it by yourself by looking how they do it or dequeuing the jquery and the enqueuing it again at the footer. Search in your theme something like this wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll download there plugin (install it) and then look at how they handle jquery in there. I'm actually creating my own theme from scratch and newer to wordpress, so going little by little.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE****

I found this answer with doing more research incase anyone want's to know how to do it.

```
function move_jquery_to_wpfooter() {
    wp_scripts()->add_data( 'jquery', 'group', 1 );
    wp_scripts()->add_data( 'jquery-core', 'group', 1 );
    wp_scripts()->add_data( 'jquery-migrate', 'group', 1 );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'move_jquery_to_wpfooter' );
```

This effectively jquery scripts right before the closing body tag.

Answer was found here on stack overflow.